# Excel vba vlookup doesn't return value

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula in my VBA:

```
Currenstock = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("G2").Value, Sheets("Producten").Range("B1:D9000"), 2, False)
MsgBox (Currentstock)
```

the msgbox does appear but it shows nothing in it.

When I do this with VLOOKUP in an excel cell instead (with the same values), it finds exactly what I wanted it to find.

My question is; why doesn't this first process return a value?
Whenever I remove worksheetfunction it also doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have a workbook and -sheet specified for all your range objects. E.g. `Range("G2")` should be along the lines of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G2")` and `Sheets("Producten")` should also have a workbook specified

Comment: @TimStack

Right now  I have done this:
' Currenstock = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("In_bestelling").Range("G2").Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Producten").Range("B1:D9000"), 2, False) But it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable you are setting with your Vlookup function is spelt differently to the Variable your are trying to return in your messagebox.

`Currenstock` vs `Curren`**t**`Stock`

Using `Option Explicit` in your macro will help to catch these.

Comment: Thank you very much. I dnot know why it doesnt just autocomplete.

Comment: Agreed, autocomplete would be very helpful. This happens to me all the time.

Comment: Autocomplete does exist in VBA, but it won't  work because you don't declare your variables. Use `Option Explicit`, and press `CTRL + Space` to autocomplete your variables

Comment: Good shout @TimStack , I didn't even think of that. I definitely don't use `CTRL + Space` enough